# What happens when you access a class-variable from inside an instance with a self-reference?

Tags: python, inheritance

One of my colleagues wrote a code similar to this:

```
class A(object):
    foo = "bar"


class B(A):
    def baz(self):
        print self.foo
```

and against my personal belief, this worked! I come from a mainly Java background, and this hurts my eyes... Personally, I would have written it like this:

```
class A(object):
    foo = "bar"


class B(A):
    def baz(self):
        print A.foo  # or dynamically determine the superclass.
```

I understand, that in Python variable names are often compared to "labels". But this still leaves a sour taste in my mouth. What are the implications of writing code like this? Is it really a bad idea? Can something go wrong?

The only *"bad"* thing I can imagine is that deeper down the class hierarchy, an instance variable may shadow the class variable... so, you could says it's... okayish?

Comment: Relevant blog post by Guido, (BDFL): http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: This works in Java too. If you have a class defined as `class A { static int x = 0;}`, then `new A().x == 0`.

Comment: If this puzzles you prepare for a _lot_ of surprises then. Python is very very permissive and let you do crazy things like dynamically reassign an object's class at runtime.... Hopefully very few coders are masochistic enough to do such a thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can basically do both.

If your class has just one parent, you can reference the variable directly with the name.

```
class A(object):
    foo = "bar"


class B(A):
    def baz(self):
        print self.foo
```

What you have done make sense if you use multi

```
class A(object):
    foo = "bar"

class A2(object):
    foo = "bar 2"

class B(A, A2):
    def baz(self):
        #print foo # would throw NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined
        #print self.foo # prints "bar"
        print A.foo # prints "bar"
        print A2.foo # prints "bar 2"
```

EDIT:
If we ignore that fact that Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, I think it behaves in the similar way.

```
public class A {
    String foo = "bar";
}

public class B extends A {

    public void baz() {
        System.out.println(this.foo);
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B();
    b.baz(); // prints "bar"
}
```

The only difference is that in Java it is accessible with `this.foo`, `super.foo` but also `foo`, while in Python you can just use `self.foo` or `<superclass>.foo`, but not `foo`

Comment: Could you also add what `print self.foo` would print? I think it should depend on Python's MRO, but it'll be a nice addition to the answer.

Comment: @ffledgling I always thought that it would return the value from the first class, `bar` in this case, but thanks I'll have a deeper look at Python's MRO and update the answer

Comment: @JanneKarila I've commented it, it was there just to demonstrate that it would throw NameError, after an exception is thrown it will not continue with execution, now it should work after copy&paste

Answer (score 3):

Well, first of all, Python is not Java. Some things are just different.

According to the semantics of Python, name resolution in classes has to work that way. Otherwise there'd be no way of calling methods from an instance, since methods are also class attributes.

You're right that an instance variable elsewhere could shadow the class variable. But in my opinion, that's a feature, not a bug. If you really wanted to be sure you were always accessing the class variable, you could do `self.__class__.foo`, but I don't think there's any need.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a complicated question. Your two code examples have slightly different behavior.

In your colleague's implementation, it is possible for an instance of `B` to have its own value of `foo`. Nothing in the above code would establish one, but you could easily do so:

```
example_B = B()
example_B.foo = 'foobar'
```

Then `example_B.baz()` would return `'foobar'`.

If implemented with your version, `example_B.baz()` would not check the instance's value. Instead, it would return `'bar'`, regardless of what had been set on `example_B`.

In practice, you should usually be able to tell when designing your class whether a name should refer to instance-specific information or to class-specific information. Only class-specific information should be declared at the class level.

Some people use class-level declarations as a shortcut to ensure that a value is available on all instances of a class even if they don't set it, but I find that this usually leads to confusion as soon as they declare a mutable variable as a "default value":

```
class BadExample(object):
    accidentally_shared_value = []
```

Instead, you should generally declare instance-specific values in `__init__`:

```
class BetterExample(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.unshared_value = []
```

Accidentally sharing mutable values is the main situation that can go wrong when misunderstanding what's a class attribute versus what's an instance attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> > The only "bad" thing I can imagine is that deeper down the class hierarchy, an instance variable may shadow the class variable

It's actually possible without any deep hierarchy at all.

```
class TestClass(object):
    var = 'foo'
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 'bar'

x = TestClass()
print x.var
>>> 'bar'
del x.var
print x.var
>>>> 'foo'
```

But it's okay in Python.